# What is the difference between 诚意 and 诚信?

Tags: word-choice, difference, synonyms

Both words generally mean **sincerity** or **honesty**, however their usage seems to be different, sometimes, but not always.

According to my understanding, you can say, for example:

> **他对我有诚意。**

but can't say:

> **他对我有诚信。**

However, you *can* say:

> **他有诚信。**

Can anyone please explain the difference? Can someone please translate the above sentences accurately, and perhaps provide a few other useful examples? Thanks.

Comment: 有诚信 have integrity, act in good faith,
bkrs：诚信genuine
honest
in good faith
honesty
integrity
sincerity and honesty, examples:以人为本， **诚信**  至上,做生意一定要讲  **诚信** ，如果弄虚作假，欺骗顾客，一定会自败声名，自断财路。职能科学、权责法定、执法严明、公开公正、廉洁高效、守法  **诚信**  的法治政府  **诚意**  good faith; sincerity, **对...诚意**  sincere towards:see jukuu's 100 samples for each, among those for  **诚意**  there are exactly 2 with  **对...诚意** :43.不过他  **对** 你总是一片 **诚意** 。82. 孙小姐怫然瞪眼道：“谁要他  **对** 我诚  **意**

Comment: 诚意 means you have sufficient motivation to do something at fair cost. 诚信 means that you want to keep a good credit history = 诚实守信。

Answer (score 2):

诚信: means honesty **and** credibility

诚意: means honesty only

You can't say:

> 他对我有诚信。

Because if somebody 有诚信, he/she will be always 有诚信, not only for you, but for everyone. So you just say 他有诚信 or 他没诚信.

You can say

> 他对我有诚意。

意 means mood here. One can be 有诚意 **now**, but wasn't other times, can be 有诚意 for **you**, but not for others.

**诚信 is a trait, 诚意 is a mood.**

You can say

> 他今天有诚意.

not

> 他今天有诚信

Answer (score 1):

诚意: your willingness towards something,

eg: 我对这生意很有诚意；让我们看到你的诚意；

诚信: credits you got, (so people hold you accountable to do something.)

eg: 你很有诚信； 你的诚信很好。

Answer (score 1):

> In '诚意'(**sincerity**); '诚'= '诚实'(honest) ; '意'= '意图' (intention)
>
> **有诚意**- having honest intention means you are **sincer**e

~

> In '诚信' (**integrity**);  '诚'= '诚实'(honest); '信'= '信用'(credibility/ trust- worthiness)
>
> **有诚信**- having honesty and credibility means you **have integrity**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone said he would do something and finally he did it. 他很有诚信
If anyone said he would do something and problaly he will do it. 他很有诚意